# Determine whether $S=\{(x,\sin(\frac{1}{x})):x \in \mathbb{R}^+\} \bigcup \{(0,0)\}$ is an open set, closed set or neither.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$$S:=\{(x,\sin(\frac{1}{x})):x \in \mathbb{R}^+\} \cup \{(0,0)\}$$
For proving that this is not an open set, I took $x=(0,0)$, and said, if this is infact an open set, then $\exists r>0 \text{ s.t. } B(x,r) \subseteq S$. Now, clearly, $(-r/2,0) \in B(x,r)$, but $ (-r/2,0) \notin S$. Thus, $S$ isn't an open set.

But how do I prove that this is a closed set/neither ?

 For $S$ to be a closed set, all its limit points will have to be inside $S$, which seems intuitively true, but I am not able to show it explicitly. Could someone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right about not being an open set. And it is not a closed set because, for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $\left(\frac1{\pi/2+2n\pi},1\right)\in S$, but$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1{\pi/2+2n\pi},1\right)=(0,1)\notin S.$$